# Ошибка при установке opencv для Python

Tags: python, opencv

При установке openCV для питона выдает ошибку.

[image: скрин]

По совету из гугла наставил уже кучу всякой всячины, типа nympu, sql и еще бог знает чего...
Пробовал откатить pip до более ранней верси и снова обновить

Подскажите, что можно еще попробовать ?

Comment: а visual studio 2017 устанавливали?

Comment: Да. Это же среда разработки, я правильно понимаю ? Разные поставил, чтоб посмотреть как ая удобнее. И PsyCharm, и CodeBLocks и эту то

Comment: у вас в ошибке просто написано, что нужно установить visual studio 2017 с https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/

Comment: сейчас удалю и переустановлю

Comment: тоже самое. Visual studio стоит, запускается нормально, но та же ошибка при установке

Comment: Не помогает... И при чем тут вообще сторонняя программа ?